# Can you publish a webtoon on a webtoon website like webtoon in comic or manga format?

Tags: publishing

Can you publish a webtoon on a webtoon website like webtoon in comic or manga format? Now, the standard [canvas has a size of 800x1280px](https://www.webtoons.com/en/challenge/webtoon-format/list?title_no=109936&page=1). I am wondering if you can cut the height or the height has to be always bigger for the web app to display it correctly, and instead of putting one panel on a single line just put it in the same 3x3 grid. I haven't seen any webtoon use a comic format, and I am wondering what might be the issues and if it's mandatory to use a webtoon format to publish it on webtoons.com.

According to [Clip Studio](https://www.clipstudio.net/how-to-draw/archives/157055):

> Splitting and exporting your work
>
> While files on Webtoon are displayed in the long, vertical scrolling
> format, each file for upload is limited to a maximum height of 1280px.
> The uploaded files are then displayed one after the other.

Nothing I read seems to suggest it's mandatory.

See also [Beginner's Guide to Making a Webtoon!](https://tips.clip-studio.com/en-us/articles/2792)

Comment: Both of you need to stop this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [rules for what can be depicted on WEBTOON](https://www.webtoons.com/en/terms/canvasPolicy), but layout isn't one of them. Though the minority, there are community-published comics ("Canvas") that use a "traditional" column format. There are even comics there that were originally published in a physical format and not reformatted (even as far as being [black and white, right to left, and, yes, column formatted](https://www.webtoons.com/en/challenge/stupid-story-manga-bl/coverinfoillu/viewer?title_no=344710&episode_no=1)).

What you won't find are "Originals" with that type of formatting. These are the comics that WEBTOON commissions exclusively for its platform. They all use vertical scroll format.

There's a good reason why column format is very rare on sites like WEBTOON: Most readers are on a mobile device, and column format is much harder to read, which translates to fewer readers. Some Canvas authors even decide to transition from a column format to vertical scroll, and the response from viewers is usually overwhelmingly positive. I'm not even sure that column format works on desktop.